# NET5 + F# - How to build several console applications into one folder

Tags: .net-core, f#, .net-5

Let's say that I have two F# projects targeting `NET5` and producing console applications. Let's call them `MyService` and `MyAdminConsole`. When I build the solution, then the folders, e.g. `...\MyService\bin\x64\Debug\net5.0` and `...\MyAdminConsole\bin\x64\Debug\net5.0` will contain:

```
...
appsettings.json
...
MyService.exe
MyService.dll
MyService.deps.json 
MyService.runtimeconfig.json
MyService.runtimeconfig.dev.json
...
```

and

```
...
MyAdminConsole.exe
MyAdminConsole.dll
MyAdminConsole.deps.json 
MyAdminConsole.runtimeconfig.json
MyAdminConsole.runtimeconfig.dev.json
...
```

where `appsettings.json`, obviously, exists only in `MyService` because it is the service, which needs the settings.

Now, I want to build both the service and the admin console into the same folder so that admin console could have access to the same `appsettings.json` and I stress the same `appsettings.json`, not a copy of it.

This seems straightforward, right? Just add a reference to `MyAdminConsole` into `MyService` project. However, when I rebuild the solution, then `MyAdminConsole.exe` and `MyAdminConsole.dll` are copied into `...\MyService\bin\x64\Debug\net5.0` but `MyAdminConsole.*.json` **are not**. Subsequently, `MyAdminConsole` won't work from that folder.

Sure, I can add post build steps and actually copy these json files where needed. However, that seems ugly and just plain wrong.

I wonder what is a proper solution? Thanks.

PS This is probably applicable to C# solutions as well but I have not checked that yet.

Comment: This feels to me like its a question about deployment not about build. At what point do you actually need everything to be in the same folder and why? (Its not an unreasonable thing to want, I'm just trying to understand the context to see if I have a useful answer)

Comment: At build time, of course, and then I will publish it or just copy that single folder. Since this is not a web app, copying should suffice. And I did explain why `MyService` and `MyAdminConsole` must be in the same folder - they must share a single `appsetting.json`. An admin console should be able to modify it and a service should be able to use it.

Comment: It would not be unreasonable for there to be a "publish" step to combine both outputs so from a _dev_ point of view the need to have both in the same place is marginal. But its still a fair question to wonder if it can be done without additional work. Hmmm.

Comment: Based on decades of experience I strongly recommend you always keep the output folders of the projects as is, because messing around with that easily leads to various kinds of trouble, and most likely at unexpected points in the future. If you don't have build and/or publish scripts already, then create it exactly for this kind of purpose. Post build steps are just fine, but I wouldn't use them to modify the output folders for this purpose. Copy to elsewhere instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly then please take a look at the workarounds proposed in https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1675